# Open latest recorded id in new page asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, html

I want to save info on database and pass the saved row's id to the new page, and then the next page must shows this id in new window. I wrote this code but just save Operation works correctly, showing new page doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
protected void btnReportWaybill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Code"] = null;
    string strId = txtCode.Text.Trim();
    SaveOperation();
    Session["Code"] = strId;

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Message", "window.open('../ExportReport/DirectAWB.aspx','_blank');", true);

}
```

Comment: Please check whether it treated as pop up or not , some borwser may block popup

Comment: don't tread popup window ,browser allow popups

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "window.open('../ExportReport/DirectAWB.aspx','_blank');", true);
```

Also make sure you are giving correct path in window.open.

Comment: have you checked that your browser is not blocking popup windows ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
must set the width and height for new page like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'ExportReport/PreManifest.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
```